# MoveIt perception - Failed to configure updater of type PointCloudUpdater

Tags: moveit, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to load an existing pointcloud into moveit but it keeps throwing an error. Specifically, it says "Failed to configure updater of type PointCloudUpdater"
Here's the console output immediately before the error:

```
Starting context monitors...
ros.moveit_ros_planning.planning_scene_monitor: Starting scene monitor
ros.moveit_ros_planning.planning_scene_monitor: Listening to '/planning_scene'
ros.moveit_ros_planning.planning_scene_monitor: Starting world geometry monitor
ros.moveit_ros_planning.planning_scene_monitor: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/base_link '
ros.moveit_ros_planning.planning_scene_monitor: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
ros.moveit_ros_perception: Failed to configure updater of type PointCloudUpdater
```

Here's my sensors.yaml file:

```
 sensors:
  - sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
    image_topic: /cloud_pcd
    max_range: 5.0
    point_subsample: 1
    padding_offset: 0.1
    padding_scale: 1.0
    filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
```

I load my pointcloud using the following console command:

```
rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud /home/Documents/out_pcd/processed_clouds/Scanner-2_rosbag.bag.pcd
```

Which publishes the pointcloud2 to the topic /cloud_pcd

Here's my sensor_manager.launch.xml:

```
<launch>
  <param name="octomap_frame" type="string" value="odom_combined" /> 
  <param name="octomap_resolution" type="double" value="0.025" />
  <param name="max_range" type="double" value="5.0" />

  <!-- Load the robot specific sensor manager; this sets the moveit_sensor_manager ROS parameter -->
  <arg name="moveit_sensor_manager" default="vehicle_model" />
  <include file="$(find vehicle_moveit)/launch/$(arg moveit_sensor_manager)_moveit_sensor_manager.launch.xml" />
  
</launch>
```

And finally, here's vehicle_model_moveit_sensor_manager.launch.xml:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find vehicle_moveit)/config/sensors.yaml" />
</launch>
```

Any advice at this stage would be appreciated. I can't seem to find any record of others having this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262241/moveit-perception---failed-to-configure-updater-of-type-pointcloudupdater/) by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-05-22**:
The PCD to pointcloud is working as expected, I can add a pointcloud2 to RVIZ and see the pointcloud.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-22**:
I'm not sure, but does the pointcloud publishes by `pcd_to_pointcloud` have its `frame_id` set correctly? If it doesn't, then I believe the PC updater won't be able to process it.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-05-22**:
You can specify the frame_id when running it from console. I've tried rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud /home/Documents/out_pcd/processed_clouds/Scanner-2_rosbag.bag.pcd 0.1 _frame_id:=/world, /odom,  /odom_combined and /base_link without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out! It was a typo in my sensors.yaml. **image_topic:** /cloud_pcd should have been **point_cloud_topic**: /cloud_pcd
For anyone else having this error, image_topic refers to depth images rather than point clouds. So obvious in hindsight.
Working as expected now.

---

Originally posted by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) with karma: 147 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0